# Number of pairs of points in a circle of distance more than $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $X$ be a set of $n$ points in a circle of radius $1$. Show that there are at most $\lfloor{n^2/4}\rfloor$ pairs of distinct points in $X$ of distance more than $\sqrt{3}$.
> Show that this bound is tight.

We can have $3$ points distancing $\sqrt{3}$ from each other. However, we cannot have four of these points, because a diagonal of the quadrilateral formed by them would be greater than $2$ (which is the diameter of the circle).

Knowing this, we construct a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices such that there is an edge between two vertices if the two points are at a distance of more than $\sqrt{3}$. Moreover, we are forbidding $K_4$ graphs in $G$. Using Turán's Theorem, the graph $T_{n,3}$ has the most edges possible, among all $K_4$-free graphs. So, my answer would be $\lfloor{n^2/3}\rfloor$.

This does not agree with the problem, the answer gives a better upper bound. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem says “more than $\sqrt3$”, not “at most $\sqrt3$”. So already your $3$ points at distance $\sqrt3$ don’t count towards the pairs. The graph you describe is $K_3$-free, and if you apply Turán’s Theorem to that, you get the desired bound of $\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}4\right\rfloor$.

The bound is tight because it’s achieved if you place $\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor$ points on one side of the circle and $\left\lceil \frac n2\right\rceil$ on the other.

Comment: Of course... clearly, we cannot have 3 such points. Many thanks for your answer.